# Duplication in the images while posting to Facebook in Android

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bitmap

I'm using facebook native sdk for posting images.Everything works well for the first time post but when i tried to post images 2nd time the previous images were displaying.
[image]
For posting images to the Facebook I'm downloading it from the server using ***Glide*** as a Bitmap & sharing it to the facebook.

The following code we are using for downloading the images:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, String, Bitmap[]>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    view.showProgressBar();
                    for (int i = 0; i < postFbShare.images.size(); i++) {
                        theBitmap[i] = Glide.
                                with(activity).
                                load(postFbShare.images.get(i).url).
                                asBitmap()
                                .into(-1, -1).
                                        get();
                    }

                    return theBitmap;
                } catch (final ExecutionException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;

            }
```

To get the share content we will pass the bitmap array(got from Asynctask) & no of images as below:

```
ShareContent shareContent = view.getShareContent(postFbShare.images.size(), bitmaps);
 btnFacebookShare.setShareContent(shareContent);
```

Comment: I have no clue what your screenshot is supposed to tell us, or why the Facebook buttons in it are circled. No clue what you are trying to ask _at all_, to be honest.

Comment: On Clicking that Facebook button a dialog box will appears where the images for that post will appears in the dialog box...when i cancel the post rather than posting it to the facebook it got saved in the draft...So next time when i click on another row or "facebook" button the images that belongs to the previous post gets appears rather than the current post @CBroe

Comment: Sounds like you need to empty your image array, before you call the dialog again.

Comment: everyTime I'm doing like this to create an array... Bitmap theBitmap[] = new Bitmap[postFbShare.images.size()];

Comment: And `postFbShare.images` is what/comes from where exactly? Does _that_ contain the images you currently want to share only?

Comment: yes it contains the correct images link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152134/discussion-between-pranesh-sahu-and-cbroe).